# AJAX and PHP get files and folders list using RecursiveIteratorIterator as needed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need get list of files and folders from server. 

I don't want get all files, folders, sub-folders at once.

I want get theirs little by little, as needed. So I use AJAX.

I use PHP. I use RecursiveIteratorIterator.

I did it without AJAX, but I can't do it **using AJAX**:

It works only for first directory (~root directory). I can't pass $name variable in function.

****Not JQuery!!!****

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['you_choose_directory'])){print "do something";}

getList("/start_folder/"); //always(

function getList($name) {
    $path = realpath($name);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        if (filetype($name) == "dir") {
            print "<a href='?you_choose_directory=" . basename($name) . "'><b>" . basename($name) . "</b></a>";
        } else {
            print "<a><div></div><b>" . basename($name) . "</b></a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function getXmlHttp(){
  var xmlhttp;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

function do_it() {
    var req = getXmlHttp();
    var list = document.getElementById('it_is_files');  
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if(req.status == 200) {
                list.innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'php.php', true);
    req.send(null);
    list.innerHTML = 'loading...';
}

do_it();
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>file list</title>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="doOnLoad();">
    <div id="it_is_files">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

(I don't know PHP.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it only works for your root directory is because of this:

```
print "<a href='?you_choose_directory=" . basename($name) . "'><b>" . basename($name) . "</b></a>";
```

You are making a link to the html page you are on, so the page reloads and everything starts over. You need to set the href of that a tag to javascript:void so the page doesn't reload. Then you need to add an onClick event handler to call your do_it() function and pass it the path to the directory whose contents you want to list. You will need to change do_it() so that it can accept a parameter.

HTML and javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>file list</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getXmlHttp(){
      var xmlhttp;
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
      if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    }

    function do_it(dirName) {
        var req = getXmlHttp();
        var list = document.getElementById('it_is_files');  
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if(req.status == 200) {
                    list.innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        req.open('GET', 'getList.php?you_choose_directory=' + dirName, true);
        req.send(null);
        list.innerHTML = 'loading...';
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="do_it('');">
    <div id="it_is_files">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

$dir = "./"; //default to root directory
if (strlen($_GET['you_choose_directory']) > 0){$dir = $_GET['you_choose_directory'];}
getList($dir);

function getList($name) {
    $path = realpath($name);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        if (filetype($name) == "dir") {
            print "<br/><a href='javascript:void' onClick='do_it(\"" . $path . "/" . basename($name) . "\")'><b>" . basename($name) . "</b></a>";
        } else {
            print "<br/><a><b>" . basename($name) . "</b></a>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Almost. Don't forget addslashes: $path = addslashes(realpath($name));

Comment: Why do you use so many `try`s to get an ActiveXObject when it seems an XMLHttpRequest object suffices?

Comment: Also, am I correct to believe that the .php file is named getList.php?